# JUnit test execution order differs across platforms

Tags: java, windows, maven, junit, centos

While running JUnit 4 tests via `mvn test` on different OS-s (CentOS and Windows) I noticed, that test classes are executed in a different order:

- on CentOS (XFS) - cannot determine the logic behind the order

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
(also tried with 1.8.0 Java HotSpot(TM))
Apache Maven 3.0.5

- on Windows (NTFS) - strictly alphabetical

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
Apache Maven 3.6.3

I understand, that unit tests should be independent (= not depend on the order)…

Still, I’d like to understand - what makes the difference in the execution order? Is it possible to achieve the same order on different platforms?

Comment: `@FixMethodOrder` annotation

Comment: On my Windows system I'm pretty sure the order is random.  I like this better.  If there are any (mistaken) dependencies on test order, randomizing the order will find them.  Make test order independent.

Comment: It's usually the result of some internal hashing function, used to do things like store the JVM data structures that reflection inspects and to provide the default `hashCode` that will influence the order of several collections.